# What is the purpose of these diodes?

Tags: diodes, rectifier, three-phase, bridge-rectifier

What is the purpose of these didoes? I couldn't find it because I don't know it's name.

Thank you.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8yt2N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Which diodes?  The SCRs or the two rectifiers?  Do you mean "What is the purpose of **this circuit**"?

Comment: Which didoes? D1 and D2? Their purpose depends on what the circuit is driving. Can you edit your question to add some context? Where did you see a circuit like this?

Comment: @TimWescott not the SCRs, two rectifiers

Comment: @Transistor it’s a rectifier used for both load supply and battery charge

Comment: @Transistor DC bus is divided into two outputs, one for battery charge and other is for supplying a load

Comment: You should show us the real circuit then, not some arbitrary part of it.

Comment: It only has 2 outputs in addition to that as I’ve mentioned above, I’ve only seen this on a paper in school and I just want to learn, that is all

Comment: Controlled rectifiers are a huge field. One could easily fill a whole book about the theory alone.

Comment: Whatever it is you're doing there, 1N4148s are probably the _least_ suitable diode you could possibly use in that position.

Comment: @Hearth: I understand this drawing is only partly accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the left is a full-bridge fully-controlled thyristor rectifier. With that circuit it's possible to turn DC into AC if the outer DC voltage is ever higher than the rectified AC voltage. The current flow is reversed then.

D1 stops this reversed current from the DC connector.

In addition, D2 and D1 function as a crowbar for reversed polarity on the DC connector.

---

There is no real reason to have D1, though, because the ability to turn DC into AC relies on firing the thyristors in the correct pattern. One could simply forbid the control logic to use that pattern.

Comment: Thank you so much, does these process have a specific name?

Comment: @DasD. Rectification...

Comment: Thank you but I don’t mean that, I mean the name of preventing reverse current

Comment: It's *preventing reverse current*.

Comment: @DasD. I apologize :) I don't mean to sound like a smarta** but rectification _does_ prevent reverse current.

Comment: @KingDuken: As the SCR (=silicon controlled rectifier) circuit does not and is still considered a *rectifier*, this is at least confusing in the context of this question. This is why I wrote "thyristor rectifier" instead.